# preg_replace to insert default value when omitted

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to work on some regex for a preg_replace that would insert a default key="value" when it is not in the subject.

Here's what I have:

```
$pattern = '/\[section([^\]]+)(?!type)\]/i';
$replacement = '[section$1 type="wrapper"]';
```

I want this to turn:

```
[section title="This is the title"]
```

into:

```
[section title="This is the title" type="wrapper"]
```

but when there is a value, I don't want it to match. This means that this:

```
[section title="This is the title" type="full"]
```

would stay the same.

I am using the negative lookahead incorrectly. The first part will always match and the (?!type) becomes irrelevant. I'm not sure how to place it so that it would work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
/\[(?![^\]]*type)section([^\]]*)\]/i
   -------------         ------
         |                  |->your required data in group 1
         |->match further only if there is no type!
```

try it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%5B%28?!%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D%2atype%29section%28%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D%2a%29%5C%5D&input=%5Bsection%20title=%22This%20is%20the%20title%22%5D%0A%5Bsection%20title=%22This%20is%20the%20title%22%20type=%22wrapper%22%5D)

Answer (score 2):

```
$your_variable = str_replace('type="full" type="wrapper"]','type="full"]',preg_replace ( '/\[section([^\]]+)(?!type)\]/i' , '[section$1 type="wrapper"]' , $your_variable ));
```

see it in action here http://3v4l.org/6NB51

Comment: That's a bit too literal I think, because I'm pretty certain the OP has other `types` other than `full`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$pattern = '~\[section\b(?:[^t\]]++|t(?!ype="))*+\K]~';
$replacement = ' type="wrapper"]';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Comment: Wait, why did you remove that `+` there? The `*` seems to prevent it form working properly now.

Comment: I tested it when you had the * and it didn't work. I accepted Anirudh's because he explained it nicely and it's closer to the formats I have elsewhere. Your solution works as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Personally, I'd use `preg_replace_callback` to process it. Something like:

```
$out = preg_replace_all(
  "(\\[section((\\s+\\w+=([\"'])(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\])*?\\3)*)\\s*\\])",
  function($m) use ($regex_attribute) {
    $attrs = array(
      "type"=>"wrapper",
      // you may define more defaults here
    );
    preg_match_all("(\\s+(\\w+)=([\"'])((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\])*?)\\2)",$m,$ma,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach($ma as $a) {
      $attrs[$a[1]] = $a[3];
    }
    return // something - you can build your desired output tag using the attrs array
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, your solution seems overly complex and hard to read compared to Anirudh's.

Comment: Just because it's more complex doesn't mean it's not as good. Quite the contrary, this is an extremely powerful solution.